# Better Grasp on Interfaces

Tags: c#

I have used a lot of abstract classes both for polymorphism, and obviously inheriting common function in subclasses.

I'm trying to use interfaces more. Yes, it's also use for polymorphism..for example using an IMyInterface param in a method that can take any subclass that implements IMyInterface.

Ok, now the thing I don't get though is why we should or always need to define our variables as IMyInterface instead of a type that has implemented that interface.

Example, take a look at this article:

http://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/archive/2008/02/14/understanding-ioc-container.aspx

Ok, specifically this:

```
  17:      private static void AppCode()
  18:      {
  19:        ConsoleLogger logger = new ConsoleLogger();
  20:        Gadget gadget = new Gadget(logger);
  21:        gadget.TurnOn();
  22:        gadget.TurnOff();
  23:      }
  24:    }
  25:  }

AppCode method (lines 19-22) is what we are interested in. A few question can be raised at this point:

   1. Why logger is of type ConsoleLogger and not ILogger? Isn't this wrong?
   2. Why gadget is of type Gadget and not IGadget? Same smell?
   3. What if we need to move logger implementer to a different layer than the ConsoleApp?
```

Here's the thing for me, I don't get why it's not a problem to just use the type Gadget and ConsoleLogger concrete methods.  Why in this top layer does it still need to be a var of type ILogger and IGadget?  I mean at this point I'm not seeing any need for polymorphism..but I"m missing the boat I guess here in my learning process.

Can someone explain why everyone wants to create interface params in your top layers for variables and assigning that variable to a type that has implemented that interface?  Why not just Gadget and ConsoleLogger, the very concrete class you want to use in the first place?  Yes Gadget and ConsoleLogger meet the contracts of the ILogger and IGadget...but I must be missing another reason here..fundamental reason.

If I make no sense, it's because I don't really know how to describe my question but I feel this is pretty clear.  Why use interface variables in a case like this?

It's almost like what I've seen out there is once you need to use a concrete type that has implemented an Interface that it looks to me that you should always set it to an interface variable, not a variable type of that subclass.  Is this right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Here's the thing for me, I don't get why it's not a problem to just use the type Gadget and ConsoleLogger concrete methods. Why in this top layer does it still need to be a var of type ILogger and IGadget? I mean at this point I'm not seeing any need for polymorphism..but I"m missing the boat I guess here in my learning process.

The whole idea of `inversion of control` is to get the dependencies out of the classes, that uses them. Accodring the code you've pasted - the `Program` is highly coupled to specific classes. I even say - it is coupled to `implementation`!

So, when you rewrite that `Program` on using of interfaces - you are free in the future to use any interface impementation you want. Let's suppose you wanted to change `ConsoleLogger` to `SyslogLogger`, or even to `CompositeLogger` which writes to several storages.

With dependencies inverted (moved outside the class) - you can do that very simple and without any modifications. As usual - dependency container configuration is some of human-readable format, xml, for example. So for changing of your program behaviour (move from one - to another logger) - only thing you need is just to change one line in config file.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control - this article describes the same thing but in correct english ))

**UPD**:

in that sample - `Program` depends on `ConsoleLogger` class. This means that the dependency is "inside" the class program. So when you move this dependency outside (for example - by passing the `ConsoleLogger` by function parameter) - it called **inversion**. And now that dependency is outside. Outside == `Program` now depends on some `ConsoleLogger` interface, not the class itself, and now `Program` does not take care how to instantiate that class object.

And `dependency container` is just a software that helps you to organize the relations/dependencies in a handy manner (as usual it is tree, dependency tree).

Comment: thanks.  I am not clear on what you mean by "get the dependencies out of the classes, that uses them"

Comment: (Let's suppose you wanted to change ConsoleLogger to SyslogLogger, or even to CompositeLogger which writes to several storages).  Ok so you're saying then if I wanted to change to another logger then after I've already done a ILogger logger = new ConsoleLogger I could then take that logger variable and do a logger = new SyslogLogger and now that variable is pointing to the new logger type via polymorphism since SyslogLogger implements ILogger?

Comment: @CoffeeAddict: added answer to 1st comment

Comment: @CoffeeAddict: Answer to 2nd: nope, the idea of inversion of control - is move the dependencies out of your class. So you should not create any objects - you should only receive that objects as functions parameters.

Comment: @CoffeeAddict: that article is not rather good, i would like to propose you to read this pages: http://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Injection-Patterns http://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Dependency-Injection-By-Hand http://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Dependency-Injection-With-Ninject

Comment: thanks, what kinds of dependencies for example?  I know this sounds really like a basic question but humor me.

Comment: also, I noticed while reading it, this sentence is a good one from wikipedia: "Offering constructors and/or setter methods that take interfaces, relieving the implementing class from having to choose an implementation"...

Comment: @CoffeeAddict: the most trivia sample I can think of: `Mailer`. Let's suppose you have an application that sends something via email. For example for debug purposes you need to have emails caught in the directory as files. You can install and setup some trivia MTA stub, **or** you can create another `IMailer` that just accepts body and put it as another file. (this is the scenario I've used several days ago)

Comment: My guess is once I grasp all this and certain scenarios that paint an example of an opportunity to use it, it will become much easier as I go to get the hang of this. It just seems overwhelming at first to understand IoC..and I highly doubt even developers who know it now, figured it out in a few weeks.  I assume you will be hitting your head a few times before you truly get it.

Comment: sorry, the Mailer is an example of dependencies?  What was that reply to in terms of which of my replies?

Comment: @CoffeeAddict: also - dependency containers can help you in organizing different workaround for different environments: testing/stage, development, production. All these environments can have a different dependency graph, but you as developer should not keep in mind all those - you should just ask your IoC to give you an `IStorage`, `IUserAuthentication`, etc etc

Comment: It was an answer to "what kinds of dependencies for example?"

Comment: good stuff on those ninject links...I like "When a class is dependent on a concrete dependency, it is said to be tightly coupled to that class"

Comment: yea, I guess I did not get your mailer example...the point that is.

Comment: "Offering constructors and/or setter methods that take interfaces, relieving the implementing class from having to choose an implementation" -- yes. You ask IoC to create one particular instance that depends on hundreds of other objects. And IoC will satisfy all that class requirements.

Comment: when you say "you should just ask your IoC to give you an IStorage, IUserAuthentication" you ultimately are saying "IoC give me the right concrete instance that implements IStorage or IUserAuthentication"...since my class contains all interface variables, or expects all Interface params, etc. the container will go and get the right instance method that I need that has implemented that interface (polymorphism lets you pass in any class obviously that has implemented x interface).

Comment: @CoffeeAddict: continuation of emailer sample: so, now you have `RealMailer` and `FileMailer`. First one sends real mails, and the second one just puts mail bodies to the files. Each mailer class need an `Smtp` instance, which it will use to send mails. So with hand instantiation it will looks like `var mailer = new Mailer(new Smtp('ip.of.smtp.serer'));`. With IoC you can simply configure your graph in the way, that `Mailer` depends on `Smtp`, and `Smtp` needs to be constructed with 'ip.of.smtp.serer'. And this work will be done automatically.

Comment: @CoffeeAddict: "since my class contains all interface variables, or expects all Interface params, etc..." --- yes. After you asked IoC - it will do a lot of dirty work to create expected instance according to the current dependency graph.

Comment: @CoffeeAddict: http://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/The-Activation-Process - here the complete process of instantiation inside Ninject is explained.